# If $A$ is invertible, prove the next property about $A+B$ and $I + BA^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is invertible, prove that $A+B$ and $I + BA^{-1}$ are both invertible matrices or both aren't invertible matrices

Comment: Try multiplying $A+B$ by the inverse of $A$ to the right.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\det(A+B)=\det(I + BA^{-1})\det(A)$